# Haskell newtype syntax

Tags: haskell, newtype

Please help me to understand the following definition:

```
newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a,w) } 

instance (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w) where 
    return a             = Writer (a,mempty) 
    (Writer (a,w)) >>= f = let (a',w') = runWriter $ f a in Writer (a',w `mappend` w')
```

Why is runWriter is declared as

```
runWriter :: (a,w)
```

when its actual type is:

```
runWriter :: Writer w a -> (a, w)
```

Once I tried with ghci I realized this must be some implicit argument since type "a" has to be determined, but what is exactly happening here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `runWriter` is a record field accessor on `Writer`. It's actually almost equivalent to

```
runWriter (Writer x) = x
```

Haskell just has records to give

1. More convient syntax since this sort of accessor code is quite common
2. The ability for functional updates
3. A few other extensions

eg

```
someWriter{runWriter = (new, values)} -- Returns a new Writer.
```

If it helps, think of it as something like a "functional getter" in the roughest sense. This might not seem terribly important with 1 field, you can always pattern match, but when you have 5 fields, records + functional updates are super helpful. See [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax) for a more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it: You can imagine defining 2-tuples like so (if the special `(,)` syntax weren't already a special built-in)

```
data  (,)  a b   =   (,)  { fst :: a, snd :: b }
```

and then `fst` and `snd` would behave as normal:

```
fst :: (a,b) -> a
fst (x,y) = x
```

(`newtype` as in your example works for types with only one value field. for types with multiple fields, `data` is needed.)